GetProperties not returning bool properties from derived class
My classes:
public class User
{
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; } 
    public string UserLogin { get; set; } 
    public bool UserActive{ get; set; } 
}

public class Userrights: User
{
    // Rechte.
    public bool right_100;
    public bool right_101;
    public bool right_102;  
    //...
}

With a SQL Query I get all the relevant data.
Then I want to get each property with the value of class Userrights.
I tried this, but I only receive the properties of User not of Userrights.
static void GetData(Userrights obj)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        property.GetValue(obj);
        MessageBox.Show(property.Name.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(property.GetValue(obj).ToString());
    }
}

I also tried it this way, but I here I didn't get anything.
static void GetData(Userrights obj)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => 
            p.PropertyType == typeof(bool) && (bool)p.GetValue(obj, null)
        );

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = (Boolean)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
}

So how can I get the bool properties of my derivied class?

That's because your Userrights doesn't contain any properties, only public fields. See what is the difference between a field and a property and GetProperties not returning all values to solve your problem.

Yes, thanks. Now I get what I want.

Why are you using Reflection in the first place? That would be a code smell to me if there isn't a very good reason.
